# What is a good way to send and receive bytes in python 3?

Tags: python, networking, tkinter

So im working on a GUI for a MUD in my networking class, i a a little stumped on how to send and receiving commands in bytes from my client to the server, the protocol of the game says that all messages are in little endian and i have been having some trouble searching methods to send and receive messages in the proper bytes can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is a link to the protocal: http://isoptera.lcsc.edu/~seth/cs435/lurk_2.0.html

and here is my code so far, where the functions print a message to the shell is where i want to send the code to the server.

```
from tkinter import *
from sys import exit

userEntry = object

def button_func():
    print("Test")

def start_func():
    messg = (6).to_bytes(1, byteorder="little")
    print(messg)

def change_func():
    messg = (2).to_bytes(1, byteorder="little")
    print(messg)

def fight_func():
    messg = (3).to_bytes(1, byteorder="little")
    print(messg)

def pvp_func():
    messg = (4).to_bytes(1, byteorder="little")
    print(messg)

def loot_func():
    messg = (5).to_bytes(1, byteorder="little")
    print(messg)

def leave_func():
    messg = (12).to_bytes(1, byteorder="little")
    print(messg)

def submit_value():
    global userEntry
    print("Entered Value: %s" % (userEntry.get()))
    e1.delete(0, END)

class TestClient(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        global userEntry
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        for n in range(3):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(n, weight=1)

        for n in range(8):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(n, weight=1)

        lb1 = Listbox(self, width=20,height=24)
        lb1.insert(1,"Players Connected")
        lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='news')

        t1 = Text(self, width=60)
        t1.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=3)

        lb2 = Listbox(self, width=20,height=24)
        lb2.insert(1,"Connected rooms")
        lb2.grid(row=0, column=6, columnspan=2, sticky='news')

        la1 = Label(self, text="Value entry:")
        la1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        userEntry = StringVar()
        global e1
        e1 = Entry(self, width=40, textvariable=userEntry)
        e1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=6)

        e2 = Button(self, text="Enter", command=submit_value)
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=5, columnspan=10)


        b1 = Button(self, text="Start", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=start_func)
        b1.grid(row=2, column=0)

        b2 = Button(self, text="Change Room", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=change_func)
        b2.grid(row=2, column=3)

        b3 = Button(self, text="FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=fight_func)
        b3.grid(row=2, column=4)

        b4 = Button(self, text="PvP FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=pvp_func)
        b4.grid(row=2, column=5)

        b5 = Button(self, text="Loot", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=loot_func)
        b5.grid(row=2, column=6)

        b6 = Button(self, text="Leave", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=loot_func)
        b6.grid(row=2, column=7)

        stats = Listbox(self, width= 20)
        stats.insert(1,"health:")
        stats.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky='news')

root = Tk()
root.title = "Test program"
tw = TestClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: All your messages fit in one byte; why not just use `bytes([6])` and `bytes([2])`, etc.?

Comment: And a socket takes bytes only *anyway*, so just send the bytes that the protocol prescribes?

Comment: Ah, the protocol involves more than one byte. You want to look at the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to produce those payloads.

Comment: Im having trouble understanding how to use  the struct module, could you give me an example?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Im having trouble figuring out the struct module can you give me an example of how to use it? maybe in the context of my code?